# PHP API library circular dependency

Tags: php, dependency-injection, client

I am writing a library in PHP which will make calls to a very basic REST API. I am trying to use dependency injection so that users can pass in their preference of PSR-18 compliant client and PSR-3 compliant logger.

The problem comes with authorization. The API accepts 2 kinds of auth. One is a permanent token which never expires and is generated once. This simply needs to be passed as a string. The other requires the user to make a HTTP request to a token endpoint. These tokens last 60 minutes and will need to be refreshed. My circular dependecy is as such: I need the lib/client to make calls to the API, but I need the token to make calls to the API. My code is loosely as follows:

```php
/**
 * Class to make calls to REST API.
 */
class Client 
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param ClientInterface $api_client PSR-18 compliant API client to make HTTP requests.
     * @param AccessTokenInterface $access_token Access token provider.
     * @param LoggerInterface|null $logger (Optional) PSR-3 compliant logger to write to logs.
     */
    public function __construct(
        private ClientInterface $api_client,
        private AccessTokenInterface $access_token,
        private ?LoggerInterface $logger,
    ) {
        if ($logger === null) {
            $this->logger = new NullLogger();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Make a request to the API.
     *
     * @param string $method HTTP method
     * @param string $uri The endpoint to query
     * @param string|null $data (conditional) Required for post and put requests.
     */
    public function makeRequest(string $method, string $uri, ?string $body = null): ResponseInterface
    {
        $request = new Request(
            $method,
            self::BASE_URL . $uri,
            array_merge(self::HEADERS, $this->access_token->getToken()),
            $body,
        );

        $this->logger->debug('Stringed request');

        try {
            $response = $this->api_client->sendRequest($request);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
            throw $e;
        }

        $this->logger->debug('Stringed response');
        return $response;
    }
}

/**
 * Class to get access token based on username and password.
 */
class CredentialsAccessToken implements AccessTokenInterface
{
    /**
     * Contructor
     *
     * @param string $username username.
     * @param string $password passwrord.
     */
    public function __construct(
        private string $username,
        private string $password,
    ) {}

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getToken(): string
    {
        // How to implement API call to get token?
    }
```

How can I maintain the DI pattern so that users can still specify their choice of client, logger and token?

Comment: You could go one step further and create a "TokenManager" class and pass that to the "CredentialsAccessToken" class. The Token Manager does the API logic.